# How to animate plotting a sector with a small circle-head in css?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to create an animation with a small circle (r = 10px) at 0° that rotates drawing a sector of a bigger radius(50px) from -30° to +30° ,

then reverse the motion removing the shape from +30° to -30°. like a windshield wipers. i dont want the rest of the circle to appear, only the sector circumference.

Also can it be colored illuminating neon blue?

EDIT: the shape is like the wifi signal logo : [image]

```css
body
{
  background-color: #000000;
  margin:auto;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:400px;


}

.container
{


  padding: 0px;
  margin:auto;



}

#e
{

  margin:auto;
  background-color: #67C8FF;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #67C8FF, 0 0 35px #67C8FF, 0 0 40px #67C8FF, 0 0 50px #67C8FF, 0 0 75px #67C8FF;


}

#d
{

  margin:auto;
  background-color: #67C8FF;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #67C8FF, 0 0 35px #67C8FF, 0 0 40px #67C8FF, 0 0 50px #67C8FF, 0 0 75px #67C8FF;


  }

#c
{
  margin:auto;
  background-color: #67C8FF;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #67C8FF, 0 0 35px #67C8FF, 0 0 40px #67C8FF, 0 0 50px #67C8FF, 0 0 75px #67C8FF;


  }


#b
{
  margin:auto;
  background-color: #67C8FF;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #67C8FF, 0 0 35px #67C8FF, 0 0 40px #67C8FF, 0 0 50px #67C8FF, 0 0 75px #67C8FF;

  }

#a
{
  margin:auto;
  background-color: #67C8FF;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 20px #67C8FF, 0 0 35px #67C8FF, 0 0 40px #67C8FF, 0 0 50px #67C8FF, 0 0 75px #67C8FF;

  }


  @keyframes
  {
    ?????

  }
```

```html
  <div class = "container">
    <div id = "e"></div>
    <div id = "d"></div>
    <div id = "c"></div>
    <div id = "b"></div>
    <div id = "a"></div>

  </div>
```

Edit:

i want it(wifi signal) to look like this neon blue color:
[image]

Comment: What is your base code? Do you have HTML you start from, do you want this in SVG with CSS animations? Have you tried making this and ran into problems?

Comment: no i want it css keyframes, the HTML is 5 <div>, container and 4 for each dot. thats it only 5 divs in the body.

Comment: Could you add the base html to your question so we can see how you are trying to achieve it? I have a feeling this is not going to be possible. I do want to say that it might be possible using an SVG in your HTML and animating that with CSS Keyfames, but your question is a bit too vague to really answer.

Comment: Ok ill add it in a minute.

Comment: I dont believe its possible to achieve this effect with just some `div` boxes.

Comment: @somethinghere What is the function in css, that is like "translate around center-line" in solid-works? that copies the element around the center-line every interval =radius, keeping the original and everything inbetween. if there is such thing in css.

Comment: There is no such thing in css to my knowledge, CSS isn't built to do these things natively as it is based on elements, not graphics. This is best accomplished with either `SVG` or `canvas`. I think. Or a `gif`.